# Resizing a PDF in Symfony

Tags: html, css, symfony, pdf, resize

I am creating an app that will make business cards. For each design of card (there will be a few variations for the company), I am using a TWIG template with the name of that design. The rendered TWIG HTML code is then changed into a PDF using the KnpSnappyBundle (https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle), and a copy saved to the database.

The issue that I have is that we need to let the user see a draft before the full size is sent off to the printer (this is automatically emailed to them), but I can not work out the resizing.

I tried:

```
$html = $this->renderView('templates/test1.html.twig');
$snappy = $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf');
$snappy->setOption('page-height', 55);
$snappy->setOption('page-width', 90);
$code = $snappy->getOutputFromHtml($html);

return new Response($code,
    200,
    array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="out.pdf"'
    )
);
```

in the controller, and then changed the page-height and page-width. In the template I have:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
        body, html {
            width: 567px;
            height: 360px;
        }
        h1 {
            font-size: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The issue is that when I do the draft, it needs to LOOK the same as the full size one, it just won't have a large file size and will fit easily on the screen. But when I change the sizes, it just puts the same size content (fonts etc) and splits it onto multiple pages.

How can I resize the entire pdf to make the draft copy??

Answer (score 0):

You can use different arguments for wkhtmltopdf. For example:

```
./wkhtmltopdf -d 300 -L 0mm -R 0mm -T 0mm -B 0mm --page-width 88mm --page-height 56mm http://habrahabr.ru out.pdf
```

You can set these commands as options in the config of knp_snappy_bundle:

```
knp_snappy:
    pdf:
        enabled:    true
        binary:     /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf #"\"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe\"" for Windows users
        options:    []
    image:
        enabled:    true
        binary:     /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage #"\"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltoimage.exe\"" for Windows users
        options:    []
```

Take a look of the documentation of https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt